# Using the Wordpress JSON API to get custom field (image)

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm trying to dynamically load images from a certain post type. I've used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to attach an image field to my post. I'm currently using this code:

```
$.getJSON('/?json=get_recent_posts&post_type=slides-verhuur&custom_fields=image', {}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

However when I run the code, the result JSON I get contains a "custom field" attribute, which have an "image" attribute, but this only contains the value of "80", which is the ID of the image. Is there a way to get the image url instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Return Value as "Image URL" instead of "Image ID" Under Custom Fields group a image field as per image shown below.

[image]

Comment: hi, this stills return the photo ID even though it is set to Image URL. I am guessing because of the theme or some custom functions ACF fails to get the URL and returns ID

Comment: Running into the same issue, even tried re-adding the images but didn't work out.

Comment: Have you manually added the custom field to the JSON? If so what code did you use?

Comment: Guys, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Here's a helpful post from developers of the ACF plugin:
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-rest-api-image-only-shows-attachment-id/
Basically just adding `?acf_format=standard` to your request URL returns the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

> $post_response->data['CFS'] = CFS()->get(false, $page->ID, array('format' => 'api'));

use 'api' instead of 'raw'